# Python "money off" deal functionality not working

Tags: python

I'm learning Python through codeacademy, and am stuck in this [lesson](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-P5YtY/1/3?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096):

My code is:

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183

    if city == "Tampa":
        return 220

    if city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222

    if city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):

    return 40 * days

    if days >= 7: 
        return days - 50

    elif days >= 3:
        days - 20 
        return days

    return days
```

Apologies for the code blocks being off. Anyway, I'm getting this error when I run the code: "Oops, try again. It looks like rental_car_cost returns 120 instead of the correct amount (100) for 3 days."

That tells me it's happening around the elif days >= 3: but not sure, any help would be great!

Comment: `return days - 20`, you also don't need elif as you cannot return twice, I would also use a dict mapping names to values in your first function. You should also be aware that your first function would return None if you did not pass a valid city

Comment: @MasterfullLiam Please indicate whether the answer were any helpful. You should accept the answer that has helped you the most and upvote any helpful answer. Please indicate whether the answer were any helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The logic in `rental_car_cost` looks incorrect. For starters, you're returning in the very first line, all the rest of the function won't execute. I think you were aiming for something like this instead:

```
def rental_car_cost(days):

    cost = 40 * days

    if days >= 7: 
        return cost - 50

    elif days >= 3:
        return cost - 20

    return cost
```

Answer (score 1):

This block is wrong:

```
elif days >= 3:
    days - 20 
    return days
```

You should instead write this:

```
elif days >= 3:
    return days - 20
```

You are subtracting 20 from `days` but you are not storing it back in `days` or in a new variable.

If it suits you, you could write

```
elif days >= 3:
    days = days - 20 
    return days
```

At this example, you are storing the result of the subtraction to `days`, so the method is returning the correct result.